# pivot_wider with duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have the following df

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), value = c("p", 
"p", "p1", "p2", "p3", "a", "b", "c", "d"), i1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

> ```
>      ID value    i1
>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
> 1     1 p         1
> 2     1 p         1
> 3     1 p1        1
> 4     1 p2        1
> 5     1 p3        1
> 6     2 a         1
> 7     2 b         1
> 8     2 c         1
> 9     2 d         1
> ```

When I tried to pivot, I got an error saying there are duplicates.

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = i1, values_fill = list(i1 = 0))
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> Values in `i1` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
> * Use `values_fn = list(i1 = list)` to suppress this warning.
> * Use `values_fn = list(i1 = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
> * Use `values_fn = list(i1 = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
> ```

I would like to identify what values are repeating for each unique ID so I could filter. Or maybe I could remove duplicates during the pivot_wider() step. The source code has name_repair which I set to "unique". Did not work!

The ideal output is:

> ```
>     p  p1  p2  p3  a  b  c  d
> 1   1   1   1   1  0  0  0  0
> 2   0   0   0   0  1  1  1  1
> ```

Comment: I tried this before posting actually! Can't work off of it. I'm trying to basically identify for each ID, what elements appear more than once so I can filter

Comment: can you show what is your expected output then?

Comment: So `df %>% 
  count(ID, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))` Or just `table(df)`

Comment: This way I can identify duplicates. But I'm kinda hoping to keep the values binary. So basically if p exists (regardless of how many times it repeats), I'd like to give it a 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in OP's attempt what they were trying to do was to remove duplicates and then pivot the data which can be done with `distinct` and  `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
 distinct() %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = i1, values_fill = list(i1 = 0))

# A tibble: 2 x 9
#     ID     p    p1    p2    p3     a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#2     2     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

---

---

We can also use `count` and `pivot_wider`

```
df %>% 
  count(ID, value) %>%
  mutate(n = +(n > 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

Comment: "+" I assume forces it into True False?

Comment: `+` changes `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0` respectively. So any `n` greater than 0 becomes 1 and less than equal to 0 becomes 0.

Comment: distinct it is! I also figured what the duplicates were by using count and filtering >1