# Merge values from columns of same column names in on column dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with two rows. In the first row I have all the headers which are repeating: "estimate1", "estimate2", "statistic", "value",  "low", "high", "method", "alternative". In the second row I have all the values which are always different. Now I want to put it in a dataframe with 8 columns where all the values go underneath similiar column names. So I want to `merge` the values from the columns with the same names and collect all the values from left to right and put them into one column. I hope that makes sens. I tried a bunch of stuff from further posts here but it didn't work out. Thanks so much!! Best!

how the dataframe looks like (just an example of it in shorter):

```
structure(list(estimate1 = 0.714007764032839, estimate2 = 0.73845425164382, 
    statistic = -1.40159874057185, value = 0.161035103302344, 
    low = -0.0586319030790906, high = 0.00973892785712839, method = "DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves", 
    alternative = "two.sided", estimate1 = 0.714007764032839, 
    estimate2 = 0.800820052750845, statistic = -6.74113868776472, 
    value = 1.57150111460365e-11, low = -0.112052677201869, high = -0.0615719002341422, 
    method = "DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves", alternative = "two.sided", 
    estimate1 = 0.73845425164382, estimate2 = 0.800820052750845, 
    statistic = -8.74919112196137, value = 2.14887453642886e-18, 
    low = -0.0763367753757128, high = -0.0483948268383366, method = "DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves", 
    alternative = "two.sided", estimate1 = 0.714007764032839, 
    estimate2 = 0.798989561276422, statistic = -5.95819444516776, 
    value = 2.55039957819806e-09, low = -0.112936786539709, high = -0.0570268079474558, 
    method = "DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves", alternative = "two.sided", 
    estimate1 = 0.73845425164382, estimate2 = 0.798989561276422, 
    statistic = -8.28057748735473, value = 1.22579375899045e-16, 
    low = -0.0748636613513149, high = -0.046206957913888, method = "DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pivot\_wider with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540383/pivot-wider-with-duplicates)

Comment: Hi R.E., Welcome to SO! Can you make a reproducible example dataset?

Comment: Sure! I mean something like this

Comment: Thanks for sending that! I mean it kind of differently as you can see up there in my example.

Comment: Thanks for adding example data... can you format it according to SO guidelines as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8400969

Comment: Sure! I hope that it is useable now. I'm sorry. Pretty new to using SO to ask questions myself. :)

Comment: Looking better... I think the data you added is a list (not a data.frame with two rows) and I'm still not quite clear what you need.